# Is there a way to append an array of objects in processing?

Tags: arrays, object, oop, processing

According to [Processing's documentation](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html), you can append an array of objects the same way, as you append any other array.
I'm doing exactly that, but I get an error:

> cannot convert from Object to sketch_220416a.planet[]

Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

```
planet[] PLANETS = new planet[1];

void setup() {
   PLANETS[0] = new planet(100, 10, 10);
   planet tb = new planet(200,3,1);
   PLANETS = append(PLANETS, tb);
   size(800, 800);
}
class planet{
   planet(float r, float x, float y)
   {
   }
   /*Some code*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs page you linked in your question:

> When using an array of objects, the data returned from the function
> must be cast to the object array's data type. For example: *SomeClass[]
> items = (SomeClass[]) append(originalArray, element)*.

In your example that would look like this:

```
PLANETS = (planet[]) append(PLANETS, tb);
```

The `(planet[])` part is just telling Processing to cast the element returned from `append` as an array of `planet` objects.